# integration of an holomorphic function on a loop

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f: D(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be continuous and holomorphic on $D(0,1) \setminus \left]0,1\right[$

I must prove that:

- for all $a,b,c \in D(0,1): \int_{[a,b,c,a]}f(z) \, dz=0$.

What I did:

$$\int_{[a,b,c,a]} f(z) \, dz= \int_{[a,b,c,a]} f(z) \, dz=\int_a^b f(z) \, dz + \int_b^c f(z)\,dz+\int_c^a f(z) \, dz = 0.$$

It must be valid in the real analysis, but I didn't use the holomorphic property of $f$, so something is missing in my work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do not see why the sum of these integrals should be $0$. You do not provide any argument for that (hence it is hard to see where that argument would fail for arbitrary $f$).

Probably, you know
$$\int_{[a, b, c, d]} g(z) \,\mathrm{d}z = 0 $$
if $g: U \to \mathbb C$ is holomorphic and the triangle lies completely in $U$.

Hence, if the triangle does not intersect with $]0, 1[$, you do not need to show anything.

Assume that the intersection of $[a, b, c, d]$ and $]0, 1[$ is a single point, that is, a corner of the triangle, let‘s say $a$. You can split the triangle in three smaller triangles: One with corner $a$ and circumference $\le \varepsilon$ and two lying completely in $D(0, 1) \setminus ]0, 1[$. The former integral is at most $\varepsilon \sup_{z \in \Delta} |f(z)|$ while the latter two are $0$.

The cases where the intersections are two points or a line can be handled similarly.

Comment: I am sorry, I wasn't precise. my (implicit) argument was the fact that in real analysis, integration over a closed path is 0, which, I know now, is not valid in complex analysis.
I didn't understand quite everything. Could you please advise what is special about the interval ]0,1[ and why in the problem conditions $f$ is holomorphic on $D(0,1) \setminus ]0,1[$?

Comment: Well, $f$ is only assumed to be holomorphic in $D(0, 1) \setminus ]0, 1[$, that‘s special about that interval. (You could choose any other (half-) line and obtain the same result.)

Comment: It also may be a good idea to draw $D(0, 1) \setminus ]0, 1[$ and some triangles on a sheet of paper.

Comment: It makes sense now after some reading, I managed to understand the one point intersection case. However I am stuck with the line intersection case. Could you please help?

Comment: Split the triangle in a quadrangle and a triangle, such that the triangle lies completely in $D(0, 1) \setminus ]0, 1[$ and two of the lines of the quadrangle have length $\le \varepsilon$. The absolute value of the integral over these lines is small while the integrals of the other two lines nearly cancel each other out. (Oh, and don‘t miss the case of two intersecting points!)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably in setting your sum of three integrals equal to zero, you have said something like 
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(z)dz + \int_{b}^{c} f(z)dz + \int_{c}^{a} f(z)dz = \int_{a}^{a} f(z)dz = 0$$
If $z$ were real, this would be perfectly legitimate. For complex integrals, the integral will in general depend on which path you choose to integrate along. For example, if $C$ is a circle of radius $1$ with centre $0$, then 
$$\int_{C} \frac{1}{z} dz = 2\pi i$$
although this could be written as 
$$\int_{1}^{1} \frac{1}{z} dz$$
if we assumed the integral only depended on the endpoints. If you then complain that $C$ is not made up of straight lines, that still doesn't fix it, because the same integral (with $C$ replaced by any triangle containing $0$) still evaluates to $2\pi i$.

It is probably better to not use the $\int_{a}^{b}$ notation when referring to complex integrals, at least until you know which theorems hold in the real case and which hold in the complex case. The holomorphicity of $f$ on a region $U$ tells you that the integral over any triangle in $U$ will vanish, but this fact is not really obvious.

Comment: Your assumption is good, you read in my mind.
Yes I find the fact that the integral over any triangle in U will vanish not obvious at all.